# Erro anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present acontece somente no Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, internet-explorer, html-helpers

Estou com um problema que não faço ideia de como resolver.
Tenho uma aplicação asp.net mvc publicada na minha máquina, onde consigo usar todas as funcionalidades (create, edit, delete) perfeitamente, seja no Chrome ou no IE.
Acontece que ao publicar no servidor de homologação, não consigo executar as funcionalidades no IE, apenas no Chrome. No IE, qualquer uma dessas funções apresenta um erro no AntiForgeryToken:

> *The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.*

O único navegador homologado do cliente é o Internet Explorer, então mudar não é uma opção.

Estou usando o helper da forma indicada e no mesmo padrão de aplicações já existentes no servidor.

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(GrupoCanaisViewModel grupoCanaisViewModel)   
{
     .
     .
     .
}
```

View:

```cs
@model DCX.ITLC.SGPCAPABILIDADE.Application.ViewModel.GrupoCanaisViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resource.CadastroDeGrupoDeCanais;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <form id="FormCreateGrupo">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                .
                .
                .         
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Já comparei as configurações do IIS de homologação com as da minha máquina e não há nada diferente, também já recriei a aplicação no servidor e nada muda.

Preciso de um norte.

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link ja me ajudou com este problema... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604336/asp-net-mvc-3-web-site-anti-forgery-token-fails-only-on-ie

Comment: Na view e na controller parece estar correto, você usa SSL na aplicação? Existe isso no seu web.config <httpCookies requireSSL="true" />? Se existir comente a linha pra ver se funciona.

Comment: o mais provável é que o ie do cliente esteja com os cookies desabilitados, dá uma olhada em opções de internet > privacidade